# how change background color of word when mouse enter with the radius of a 30px*30px circle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The scenario is that in normal mode (before the hover) the color of the text should be in the form of a gradient.
And when the mouse is placed on any letter, the range of the same letter will be created in the form of a circle with the size of 30px*30px. Both in hover mode and non-hover mode, I have to use gradient.

I want to create a circular hover with a gradient of linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 33, 44, 0.5) 0%, rgba(25, 50, 25, 0.3) 100%) when the mouse hovers over each letter.
Considering that the fill is related to the circle with the color #f7f8fa, but I want it to be transparent so that in case of hovering, I can only use its circular mode. Not from its color. But if fill: transparent; Yes, the mouse is lost.
Another problem is that when I use the gradient for the normal mode (before hover), the color change does not occur when hovering.

Now my question is, is what I have done right?
Is there any other way I can use the gradient both normally and hovered.

```js
const bigBall = document.querySelector(".cursor__ball--big");

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

// Move the cursor
function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to(bigBall, 0.4, {
    x: e.pageX - 15,
    y: e.pageY - 15,
  });
}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to(bigBall, 0.3, {
    scale: 4,
  });
}

function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to(bigBall, 0.3, {
    scale: 1,
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #010101;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}

body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
}

body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #f7f8fa;
}

body .myText {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body .myText h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
}

body .myText h1 span {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(26, 33, 44, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
          <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
        </svg>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="myText">
  <h1>
    <span class="color-letters">Get to know more about</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically on hover of the letters, you want them to temporariily light in gradient colors?

Answer (score 0):

For gradient colors, you should use the background-image:linear-gradient() property, and I don't think you can resize a letter to become a circle, you'd have to switch it with a div or something similar to that.